# How to add an image to an SSRS report with a dynamic url?

Tags: reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I'm trying to add an image to a report. The image src url is an [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) that takes a few query string parameters. Here's an example:

```
<img src="Image.ashx?item=1234567890&lot=asdf&width=50" alt=""/>
```

I added an **Image** to a cell and then set **Source** to External and **Value** to the following expression:

```
="Image.ashx?item="+Fields!ItemID.Value+"&lot="+Fields!LotID.Value+"&width=50"
```

But when I view the report, it renders the image html as:

```
<IMG SRC="" />
```

What am I missing?

**Update**

Even if I set **Value** to "image.jpg" it still renders an empty src attribute. I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I'm using this with a VS 2008 ReportViewer control in Remote processing mode.

**Update**

I was able to get the images to display in the Report Designer (VS 2005) with an absolute path (http://server/path/to/http/handler). But they didn't display on the Report Manager website. I  even set up an [Unattended Execution Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156302.aspx) that has access to the external URLs.

Comment: If you add a new text box on the report and get it to display the result of the same expression (online debugging!!) what does it show?

Comment: Good idea, but it displays the correct url.

Comment: Are ssrs and iis for the image on the same box?

Comment: No, the images are on a separate web server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a SSRS Report that displays the information about the countries of the users of a site that we support at work. This is based on the IIS log data. On this report, in the first column of the table is an image field that holds a small .gif of the flag for each country. I was running into the same exact issue described in the question above. The path to the external image was calculated in the report’s query based on the country code. I initially setup the URL to point to something like http://www.mystaticcontent.com/fotwimg/us.gif for a United States flag and so forth. All I got was a red X broken image displayed in the report. Then I found [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156482.aspx) that shined some light on the issue for me.

This is what I did with the report to make it work:

1. Moved the fotwimg folder that has all the gifs from the static content server to the local SSRS machine, which also has a web server running on it.
2. Setup a virtual directory on the default web site in the local SSRS machine IIS Manager.
3. Then I changed the report query to refer to the image in the local SSRS machine, by machine name, like this http://mylocalssrsmachine/fotwimg/us.gif
4. Voila, it works… or at least it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was trying to avoid putting the images on the report server. I wanted to display thumbnails that linked to the full size images, but I ended up using the hyperlink action on a normal text field instead. I'll have to remember this for the next time it comes up.

Comment: In SQL Server 2008, Report Server no longer uses IIS. Do you guys know how/where to install the images on the report server?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a fully qualified path?

```
http://<servername>/images/image1.jpg
```

[More Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156482.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I was able to get the images to display in the Report Designer (VS 2005) with an absolute path. But they didn't display on the Report Manager website.

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem too..

I have looked at the SSRS error logs, and the IIS server logs.  Some findings:

1. External images with URLs to static images work.  (e.g. http://intranet/site/logo.jpg)
2. I can add parameters to static image URLs and it still works.  (e.g. http://intranet/site/logo.jpg?foo=1)  The parameter will be ignored, and the image displays.  This suggests that SSRS is not choking on the ?.
3. If I link the external image to an ASPX page that returns a report with no parameters (e.g. http://intranet/site/image.aspx), it still doesn't work.
4. IIS logs show the report server requesting the image, and getting a 200 OK response.
5. Report server logs show this:

> webserver!ReportServer_0-116!14cc!01/09/2012-12:20:29:: i INFO:
>   Processed report. Report='/Path/ReportName', Stream=''
>   ui!ReportManager_0-115!7b8!01/09/2012-12:20:29:: Unhandled exception:
>   System.Web.HttpException: File does not exist.    at
>   System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String
>   virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response)
>   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   
>   I wonder if SSRS is doing something boneheaded like adding the "correct" file extension before saving the file?

i.e. something like (1) SSRS downloads /Page.aspx, which supplies an image with Content-Type: image/jpg; (2) SSRS saves this to a temporary folder with a filename like tempname.aspx.jpg; (3) SSRS looks for tempname.aspx to incorporate the image into the report; (4) Error

I suppose you could test this by handling .jpg requests in code-behind... Unfortunately that's beyond my ASPX skills at the moment.

Comment: did you ever get to find the solution to this? My external image has worked for 6 months. and now I get IMG tag onerror=this.errored=true; rrored="true"

Comment: @BobNoobGuy Sorry, no.

Answer (score 0):

My case: Load from localhost depending on product's code.

> Image.Source= "http://**LOCALHOST**/IMG/" + Fields!CODE.value + ".jpg"

Problem: Sometimes file is uploaded with extension ".png"; so it's needed a FileExists validation.

Solution: 
1)Add auxiliar table

> PRODUCT_PHOTO_EXTENSION
>
> > id (FK references PRODUCT)
> >     extension (varchar)

2)Create Store Procedure. Do the FileExists validation on sql and store the extension found in PRODUCT_PHOTO_EXTENSION.extension:

```
insert into PRODUCT_PHOTO_EXTENSION 
SELECT A.id,'.JPG' FROM PRODUCT A LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_PHOTO_EXTENSION AF ON A.id=AF.id WHERE AF.id IS NULL AND Matriz is null and dbo.FileExists('D:\directory\' + code + '.jpg')=1
 insert into PRODUCT_PHOTO_EXTENSION 
SELECT A.id,'.PNG' FROM PRODUCT A LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_PHOTO_EXTENSION AF ON A.id=AF.id WHERE AF.id IS NULL AND Matriz is null and dbo.FileExists('D:\directory\' + code + '.jpg')=1
```

3)Load image file using this field.
(SSRS; image.source expression)

```
Iif(Fields!EXTENSION.Value<>"", "http://LOCALHOST/IMG/" & Fields!CODE.Value & Fields!EXTENSION.Value, "" )
```

4) Result: Load image according it extension; avoid that red "x".

Hope it helps