# SSRS report external image

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

This is SSRS 2012 SQL Server 11.00.2218

When I have external image in report using `http://i.imgur.com/g3D5jNz.jpg` it works.

but when I use `file:///\\ImageServer\April.jpg` 
I got this error on the html

```
<IMG onerror=this.errored=true; src="" errored="true">
```

I have had this working for about 1 year. Then suddenly stop working. 
Steps I have done to troubleshoot and still not fixing the issue:

1. Check execution account has access to \ImageServer\April.jpg confirmed execution account has access to the imageServer and the file - DONE
2. Unload antivirus on the report server then test - DONE
3. Reboot report server - DONE but I will try this again
4. I looked in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles, and found no error for image related or any error related to the specific report I run

Clues I notice that I don't know how to troubleshoot

1. when using imgur jpg, the html img src is using some web service AXD file ReportViewerWebControl.axd. I am guessing it uses this to resize or convert the image some how. is it possible that an error happen during conversion/resize?

Could you please suggest how to troubleshoot this further?

other stackoverflow user have the same problem. (not the original post. but one of the answer post.) by John Fouhy
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8782471/2635566
The same symptomps, but I don't see the same error message on John Fouhy's post (yet)

Comment: I just found out that graph are also not working on my report server. we are looking into repairing the report server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623002/ssrs-2012-charts-not-rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SSRS 2012 Charts Not Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623002/ssrs-2012-charts-not-rendering)

The solution seems to be the same as question above. Something is corrupted in the installation and

I was able to resolve the problem by running a repair operation from the SQL Server Installer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Answer in the example you linked about? :

> - Moved the img folder that has all the gifs from the static content server to the local SSRS machine, which also has a web server 
>     running on it.
> - Setup a virtual directory on the default web site in the local    SSRS machine SIIS Manager.
> - Then I changed the report query    to    refer to the image in the local SSRS machine, by machine name,   like this
>     http://mylocalssrsmachine/fotwimg/us.gif    Voila, it works… or at
>     least it worked for me.

Seems like you may just need to point the file to your server.

Comment: I have further development on this that my SSRS Chart or graph are also not working. we are looking into rebuilding / repairing the report server